# Selecting the text (innerhtml) from an asp.net control with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have an asp.net gridview with and icon on each row, that when clicked i wish to create a popup with editable text boxes/input fields in. and these text boxes and input fields are to contain the existing text from the row icon i just clicked on.

i thought i could do it like this but it gets the text from classes, but not from id's see bottom row of code:

```
$(".imgEditFields").click(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var strServiceID = $(".clHiddenServiceID", row).text();
        var strTitleOfDoc = $(document).attr('title');
        var strSessionUser = strTitleOfDoc.replace("Order Tracking for ", "");
        var strPSTNNumber = $(".clHiddenPSTNNum", row).text();
        var strPSTNNum = strPSTNNumber.replace(/'/g, "");
        $('#popupTrackerEditFields h1:first').text("Edit Record " + strPSTNNum);
        var strSuppOrdNo = $("#lblSupplierOrderNum", row).text();
```

Below are my comments having tried several permatations of the comment/replies from you all

```
        $(".imgEditFields").click(function () {
        //I get the row with the icon that was clicked on
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var strServiceID = $(".clHiddenServiceID", row).text();
        var strTitleOfDoc = $(document).attr('title');
        var strSessionUser = strTitleOfDoc.replace("Order Tracking for ", "");
        var strPSTNNumber = $(".clHiddenPSTNNum", row).text();
        var strPSTNNum = strPSTNNumber.replace(/'/g, "");
        $('#PopUpTrackerEditFields h1:first').text("Edit Record " + strPSTNNum);
        var strSuppOrdNo = $(".clSupplierOrderNumber", row).text();
        //All the above work great and i get what is expected, the problem begins blow when trying to select by //the id (in that row)

        //The below line achieves what i want visually but i cannot gaurantee its the correct row can i?
        $('#MainContent_tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo').val(strSuppOrdNo);
        //The below line does not work as suggested by the replies and i have tried with HTML, val, Text etc
        $('#<%=tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo.ClientID%>', row).html(strSuppOrdNo);
        //the blow works again not sure if it is selecting the correct row each time
        $('#MainContent_tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo').attr('title', 'Edit your Supplier no here for ' + strPSTNNum);
```

Comment: How you get `strServiceID` value? Do it again for your `strSuppOrdNo `. Add a class to your `lblSupplierOrderNum` element and fetch it: `var strSuppOrdNo = $(".lblSupplierOrderNum", row).text();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the element ID being generated by .NET. I'd say to use the ID of the control, but this is going to be nasty as your controls are in a GridView, and will be unpredictable.

Best bet is to use a class on your textbox (using CssClass) and selecting that for the row, as you've previously done.

Comment: I think i am going to try this also

Comment: so now i changed the id's into classes my rowdatabound event cannot find the id's eg: lblSupplierOrderNum = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSupplierOrderNum");
Is there an alternative to find the label by class?

Comment: Noo, keep the ID as well as adding the class.

Comment: oops ok ill have to fix that noob mistake and yes i am a noob lol

Comment: Ok i have tried the above and added my findings in to the original query (because of size) still not quite there.

Comment: In your code above, you're still not selecting by Css class... I'd expect something like $('.SuppOrderNo', row)

Comment: yes Chris thanks ill go try that (im sure there was a reason why i particularly want to use ID though, but im sure ill find out)

Comment: Hi Chris i spotted the problem, the $('#<%=tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo.ClientID%>', row).html(strSuppOrdNo); is incorrect because i was refering to the 'row' and its not in the row i want, tbPopUpEditSuppOrdNo is in the popup - remove ',row' and swap html for val and it works \0/  Thanks for your help you and all

Answer (score -1):

Since these are ASP.NET controls, ID's are rendered differently. You can target them with the following syntax:

```
$("#<%= idOfControlHere.ClientID%>")
```

For one of your ID's, here's an example:

```
$("#<%= lblSupplierOrderNu.ClientID %>", row).text();
```

Comment: Surely lblSupplierOrderNu won't be available due to it being in a GridView row?

Comment: If you are working with `GridView`, so you shouldn't work with `ID`s.

Comment: Totally forgot to add Client ID to this. Fixed

Comment: i just get The name 'lblSupplierOrderNum' does not exist in the current context